# JWT authentication with email/password, facebook and google with seperate API and client service (Java Spring Boot, Angular)

Tags: angular, rest, authentication, spring-boot, jwt

I recently wrote a small full stack web application with a seperate rest api (Node.JS) and a client (React). There I implemented stateless authentication with JWT. For that, I used npm packages **passport**, **passport-facebook-token**, **passport-google-token** and **passport-local**. With this setup I was able to present the user an email/password login, but also logins via **Facebook** and **Google**.

Before I go further into the details, here is my main question: **Is it possible to implement state-/sessionless authentication with JWT using email/password, Google AND Facebook signin while using Jaca Spring Boot as a RESTful API and Angular 5 as a client (completely separated projects running on different ports/servers)?**

In short, I implemented this behaviour as follows in the NodeJS/React application:

**NodeJS API - Different routes for local, facebook and google login:**

```
router.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
  return passport.authenticate('local-login', (err, token, userData) => {
    processAuthResponse(err, res, token, userData);
  })(req, res, next);
});

router.post('/facebook', (req, res, next) => {
  return passport.authenticate('facebook-token', (err, token, userData) => {
    processAuthResponse(err, res, token, userData);
  })(req, res, next);
});

router.post('/google', (req, res, next) => {
  return passport.authenticate('google-token', (err, token, userData) => {
    processAuthResponse(err, res, token, userData);
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

Here processAuthResponse() just checks the passed args from passport and sends some final json to the client.

**NodeJS API - Passport Facebook Token Strategy. Summary: Getting the profile information from facebook, check in database, if user with mail exists (otherwise create) and create a JWT to send to the React client.**

```
import FacebookTokenStrategy from 'passport-facebook-token';

import config from '../../config';
import logger from '../services/logger';
import authService from '../services/authService';
import { User } from '../sequelize/models';

const facebook = config.AuthProviders.Facebook;

export default new FacebookTokenStrategy(
  {
    clientID: facebook.ClientID,
    clientSecret: facebook.ClientSecret,
    session: false
  },
  (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
    process.nextTick(() => {
      if (!profile.emails) {
        logger.error('Facebook profile has no email address');
        return done({
          success: false,
          message: 'Das Facebook-Profil enthält keine E-Mail Adresse. Füge ihm eine E-Mail Adresse hinzu oder registriere dich mit deiner E-Mail Adresse'
        });
      }

      User.findOne({
        where: { email: profile.emails[0].value } // TODO: How do I know the main email address of profile?
      }).then(user => {
        if (user) {
          const updateData = authService.getSequelizeUpdateObjectForUser(
            user,
            profile.name.givenName,
            profile.name.familyName,
            profile.photos[0].value // TODO: How do I know the main picture of profile?
          );
          if (updateData) {
            user.update(updateData).then(updatedUser => {
              const token = authService.createJwtFromUser(updatedUser.get({
                plain: true
              }));
              return done(null, token);
            });
          } else {
            const token = authService.createJwtFromUser(user.get({
              plain: true
            }));
            return done(null, token);
          }
        } else {
          const email = profile.emails[0].value; // TODO: How do I know the main email address of profile?
          const firstName = profile.name.givenName;
          const lastName = profile.name.familyName;
          const imageUrl = profile.photos[0].value; // TODO: How do I know the main picture of profile?

          authService.createUser('facebook', email, firstName, lastName, imageUrl, (newUser, error) => {
            if (!newUser) {
              logger.error(error);
            }

            const token = authService.createJwtFromUser(newUser);

            return done(null, token);
          });
        }
      });
    });
  }
);
```

**NodeJS API - Nearly the same with local strategy:**

```
import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';
import { Strategy as LocalStrategy } from 'passport-local';

import logger from '../services/logger';
import authService from '../services/authService';
import { User, UserAuth } from '../sequelize/models';

const ErrorCodes = require('../constants/ErrorCodes');

export default new LocalStrategy(
  {
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password',
    session: false,
    passReqToCallback: true
  },
  (req, email, password, done) => {
    const userData = {
      email: email.trim(),
      password
    };

    User.findOne({
      where: { email: userData.email },
      include: [{ model: UserAuth }]
    }).then(user => {
      if (!user) {
        logger.info(`Local login: User with email '${email}' not found`);
        const error = new Error('E-Mail oder Passwort falsch');
        error.name = ErrorCodes.INCORRECT_CREDENTIALS_ERROR;
        return done(error);
      }

      // TODO: What to do if email is not verified yet?

      user = user.get({ plain: true });

      if (!user.UserAuth || !user.UserAuth.password) {
        logger.info(`Local login: No UserAuth object or password for user with id ${user.id}`);

        const error = new Error('E-Mail oder Passwort falsch');
        error.name = ErrorCodes.INCORRECT_CREDENTIALS_ERROR;

        return done(error);
      }

      bcrypt.compare(password, user.UserAuth.password, (err, isMatch) => {
        if (err) return done(err);

        if (!isMatch) {
          logger.info('Local login: Password did not match');

          const error = new Error('E-Mail oder Passwort falsch');
          error.name = ErrorCodes.INCORRECT_CREDENTIALS_ERROR;

          return done(error);
        }

        const token = authService.createJwtFromUser(user);

        return done(null, token);
      });
    });
  }
);
```

And there is also a Google token strategy, which works similar to the facebook token implementation.

**React Client - Facebook Login Component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { FacebookLogin } from 'react-facebook-login-component';
import { Icon } from 'antd';

import './style.css';

import config from '../../../../config';
import authService from '../../../../services/authService';

class FacebookLoginButton extends Component {
  loginFacebook = res => {
    authService.loginFacebook(res.accessToken);
  };

  render = () => {
    return (
      <FacebookLogin
        socialId={config.AuthProviders.Facebook.ClientID}
        className="login-btn login-btn-facebook"
        language="de_DE"
        scope="public_profile,email"
        responseHandler={this.loginFacebook.bind(this)}
        xfbml={true}
        version="v2.5"
      >
        <Icon type="facebook" /> Mit Facebook anmelden
      </FacebookLogin>
    );
  };
}

export default FacebookLoginButton;
```

Here, react-facebook-login-component is a downloaded npm package. Something similar is present for google. I implemented the email/password login form by myself. All these components trigger my authService which do API calls (with axios) to the auth api routes (/auth/login, /auth/facebook, /auth/google).

And now again:

I want to have the same behavior in my new full stack application with **Java Spring Boot** for the RESTful API and **Angular 5** for the client, which are both separated projects.

Requirements listed:

- RESTful API service with Java Spring Boot
- SPA Client with Angular 5
- Session-/Stateless authentication with Json Web Token (Server signs the token, client stores it and sends it with every server request)
- When logging in with email/password, server should pass a new JWT to the client
- When logging in with Facebook or Google, server should also pass a new JWT (an own one, not the access token from the social provider itself) to the client

I now have my Java Spring Boot REST Api implemented with a /login route which already creates JWT's for local login. It's derived from this tutorial: https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-spring-security-jwt-mysql-react-app-part-2/

However, I have no clue, how to implement both together: Email/Password and Social Provider (Facebook/Google) authentication as I am really new to Java Spring Boot.

Is it something where I need **Spring Social** (I don't know how it is maintained nowadays) or is **Spring Security** enough for the case?

Thank you so much in advance for every little tip you will answer here!